# Batch list folder, count pdf files and get file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a summary of all the files that I received weekly from other department. The folder structure shown below. Each folder will contain multiples pdf files and only 1 .docx file. So, i would like to list down the folder name, count total pdf files inside and get the name of docx file. If docx missing, show "missing", is this possible too?

I did try this code, but this will show all files in the folder instead.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /B /A /S *') DO (
for %%D in ("%%~dpF\.") do echo/ FolderName: %%~nxD ^| FileName: %%~nxF
)
pause
```

**UPDATE:Today while Im testing suggested code, they send me last week file. AND to my surprised, the other department changed folder structure (facepalm!). Below updated folder structure for reference.**

Updated folder structure:

```
Current
|count.bat
|--FolderA-Folder1-Nov 2020.docx
|                 -pdf1.pdf
|                 -pdf2.pdf
|                 -pdf3.pdf
|                 -pdf4.pdf
|          Folder2-Dec 2020.docx
|                 -pdf1.pdf
|                 -pdf2.pdf
|                 -pdf3.pdf
|                 -pdf4.pdf
|--FolderB-Folder1-Nov 2020.docx
|                 -pdf1.pdf
|                 -pdf2.pdf
|                 -pdf3.pdf
|                 -pdf4.pdf
|          Folder2-Dec 2020.docx
|                 -pdf1.pdf
|                 -pdf2.pdf
|                 -pdf3.pdf
|                 -pdf4.pdf
|--FolderC-Folder1-Nov 2020.docx
|                 -pdf1.pdf
|                 -pdf2.pdf
|                 -pdf3.pdf
|                 -pdf4.pdf
```

Expectation Results

```
FolderName: Folder A Folder 1    PDFtotal: 4pdfs   DocFile: Nov 2020.docx
FolderName: Folder A Folder 2    PDFtotal: 4pdfs   DocFile: Dec 2020.docx
FolderName: Folder B Folder 1    PDFtotal: 4pdfs   DocFile: Nov 2020.docx
FolderName: Folder B Folder 2    PDFtotal: 4pdfs   DocFile: Dec 2020.docx
FolderName: Folder C Folder 1    PDFtotal: 4pdfs   DocFile: Nov 2020.docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original Script

The [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) without the `/B` option displays the count of matching items in the penultimate line, which could be captured and parsed by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Since you have got a flat directory structure, I would not do a recursive approach (like `dir /S` or `for /R`).

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=."         & rem // (target directory; `.` is current, `%~dp0.` is parent)
set "_MASK=Doc*.docx" & rem // (pattern to find particular file)
set _LIST="pdf"       & rem // (space-separated list of file extensions without `.`)

rem // Loop through immediate sub-directories of the target directory:
for /D %%D in ("%_ROOT%\*") do (
    rem // Return name of current sub-directory without trailing line-break:
    < nul set /P ="FolderName: %%~nxD    "
    rem // Loop through given list of file extensions:
    for %%E in (%_LIST%) do (
        rem // Initialise variables:
        set /A "CNT=0, NUM=0" & set "NAME="
        rem // Capture number of matching files from last but one line of `dir`:
        for /F "eol= " %%C in ('2^> nul dir /A:-D-H-S "%%~D\*.%%~E"') do (
            2> nul set /A "CNT=NUM, NUM=%%C"
        )
        rem // Return count of matching files without trailing line-break:
        < nul call set /P ="PDFtotal: %%CNT%%%%~Es   "
    )
    rem // Find file that matches the given pattern (assuming there is only one):
    for %%F in ("%%~D\%_MASK%") do set "NAME=%%~nxF"
    rem // Return name of found file, with trailing line-break this time:
    call echo DocFile: %%NAME%%
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The option `/A:-D-H-S` of the `dir` command in the code prevents hidden and system files from being counted; change it to `/A:-D` if you do want to regard them as well.

---

#### Updated Script

In the following you will find the new code adapted to your changed directory structure (you will notice that there were only a few modifications necessary):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=."           & rem // (target directory; `.` is current, `%~dp0.` is parent)
set "_MASK=* 2020.docx" & rem // (pattern to find particular file)
set _LIST="pdf"         & rem // (space-separated list of file extensions without `.`)

rem // Loop through immediate sub-directories of the target directory:
for /D %%S in ("%_ROOT%\*") do (
    rem // Loop through next level of sub-directories:
    for /D %%D in ("%%~S\*") do (
        rem // Return names of current sub-directories without trailing line-break:
        < nul set /P ="FolderName: %%~nxS %%~nxD    "
        rem // Loop through given list of file extensions:
        for %%E in (%_LIST%) do (
            rem // Initialise variables:
            set /A "CNT=0, NUM=0" & set "NAME="
            rem // Capture number of matching files from last but one line of `dir`:
            for /F "eol= " %%C in ('2^> nul dir /A:-D-H-S "%%~D\*.%%~E"') do (
                2> nul set /A "CNT=NUM, NUM=%%C"
            )
            rem // Return count of matching files without trailing line-break:
            < nul call set /P ="PDFtotal: %%CNT%%%%~Es   "
        )
        rem // Find file that matches the given pattern (assuming there is only one):
        for %%F in ("%%~D\%_MASK%") do set "NAME=%%~nxF"
        rem // Return name of found file, with trailing line-break this time:
        call echo DocFile: %%NAME%%
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "spaces=                         "
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /B /AD /S *') DO (
 rem new foldername in %%F
 set "foldername=%%~nxF%spaces%"
 set /a pdfcount=0
 set /a docxcount=0
 set "docxmessage=missing"
 for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A-D "%%F\*"') do (
  if /i "%%~xD"==".pdf" set /a pdfcount+=1
  if /i "%%~xD"==".docx" set /a docxcount+=1&set "docxmessage=%%~nxD"
 )
 set "pdfcount=%spaces%!pdfcount!"
 if !docxcount! gtr 1 (set "docxcount= MULTIPLE") else (set "docxcount=")
 echo/ FolderName: !foldername:~0,20! PDFtotal: !pdfcount:~-3!pdfs  Docfile: !docxmessage! !docxcount!
)
```

Note that the first `dir` command now contains `AD` to list directories only.

With each directoryname, record it in `foldername` and add some spaces at the end. Reset the counters and establish the `missing` value in the `docxmessage`.

Then get the filename list within the directory found, count each .pdf and .docx and if any .docx is found, record its name in `docxmessage`

Modify `docxcount` to a message if more than 1 `.docx` is present, and *empty* otherwise

When the directory-scan is finished, apply some spaces to the start of `pdfcount` and then produce your output line using the current values of the variables and using the modifiers to produce the first 20 characters of the padded directoryname and the last 3 characters of the padded pdfcount.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.

Fixed : `for /F %%D...` needed "delims=" to assign the *whole* filename to `%%D`

Revised code for new structure:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD U:\sourcedir
set "spaces=                         "
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /B /AD /S *') DO (
 rem new foldername in %%F
 set "foldername=%%~nxF%spaces%"
 rem find parent directory
 FOR /F "delims=" %%Q IN ("%%~dpF\.") DO SET "parent=%%~nxQ%spaces%"
 rem is a leaf directory if this directory has no subdirectories
 SET "isleaf=Y"
 FOR /F "delims=" %%Q IN ('dir /B /AD "%%F"') DO SET "isleaf="
 set /a pdfcount=0
 set /a docxcount=0
 set "docxmessage=missing"
 for /f  "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A-D "%%F\*" 2^>nul') do (
  if /i "%%~xD"==".pdf" set /a pdfcount+=1
  if /i "%%~xD"==".docx" set /a docxcount+=1&set "docxmessage=%%~nxD"
 )
 set "pdfcount=%spaces%!pdfcount!"
 if !docxcount! gtr 1 (set "docxcount= MULTIPLE") else (set "docxcount=")
 IF DEFINED isleaf echo/ FolderName: !parent:~0,20! !foldername:~0,20! PDFtotal: !pdfcount:~-3!pdfs  Docfile: !docxmessage! !docxcount!
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

Some small additions to the code.

first, find the parent directoryname. By using the directoryname in `%%F` and adding `\.`, the resultant resolved string appears to be a filename, the name and extension of which is the parent directory; store this in `parent` with padding.

Next, determine whether this is a leaf directory. Set the flag `isleaf` to assume it is a leaf directory, then perform a `dir/ad` so that any detected subdirectory name will clear the flag.

Then just process the directory as before, using `2^>nul` to suppress `file not found` messages if the directory `%%F` contains no files.

...And only generate the report line if `isleaf` is defined, with the parent directoryname added.

Answer (score 0):

This can be placed into a .bat file script and run in cmd.exe. Note that this does not identify directories which contain no .pdf file, no .docx file, or multiple .docx files.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\src\t';" ^
    "foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {" ^
    "    $PdfCount = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir.fullname -Filter '*.pdf').Count;" ^
    "    if (($null -ne $PdfCount) -and (0 -ne $PdfCount)) {" ^
    "        $DocxFiles = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir -Filter '*.docx');" ^
    "        if ($null -ne $DocxFiles) { $DocxFile = $DocxFiles[0] } else { $DocxFile = 'none' };" ^
    "        """FolderName: $($Dir.Name)  PDFtotal: $($PdfCount.ToString())pdfs  DocFile: $DocxFile""";"  ^
    "    }" ^
    "}"
```

It would be easier to put the script into a file.

=== Get-DocxAndPdfCount.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory
foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {
    Write-Verbose "dir is $($Dir.fullname)"
    $PdfCount = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir.fullname -Filter '*.pdf').Count
    Write-Verbose $PdfCount
    if ($null -ne $PdfCount -and 0 -ne $pdfCount) {
        Write-Verbose $PdfCount
        $DocxFiles = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir -Filter '*.docx')
        if ($null -ne $DocxFiles) { $DocxFile = $DocxFiles[0] } else { $DocxFile = 'none' }
        "FolderName: $($Dir.Name)  PDFtotal: $($PdfCount.ToString())pdfs  DocFile: $DocxFile"
    }
}
```

Then, run it in a PowerShell console using:

```
.\Get-DocxAndPdfCount
.\Get-DocxAndPdfCount -Verbose      # to see debugging information
```

Run from cmd.exe using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Get-DocxAndPdfCount'
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Get-DocxAndPdfCount" -Verbose
```